# Sentence-initial capitalization, lexing and GF

Tags: gf

I know that, in the GF shell, I can use the command `put_string` along with the lexer `lextext` to convert a string into a list of tokens (which can then be parsed). This lexer “understands” punctuation and, crucially, it also converts what it thinks is sentence-initial punctuation into lower case:

```
> put_string -lextext "This is my house."
this is my house .
```

However, if my grammar contains tokens with initial capitals (which is not at all unusual), and if such a token happens to appear at the beginning of a sentence, the lexer lower-cases it, making the token list unparsable by my grammar:

```
> put_string -lextext "France is my home."
france is my home .
```

My question: Is there any way to make this or any other lexer aware in more detail of which tokens it should and shouldn’t lower-case? Perhaps by making the lexer “see” the grammar for which it is lexing?

Or are lexers not in vogue any more, and am I expected to handle these things (sentence-initial capitalization, punctuation, binding tokens) on my own, completely outside GF? How do people handle these things in their GF applications usually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality in GF, and afaik no plans have been discussed to include it. Usually people use one or more of the following strategies:

- External NLP tools to preprocess the output, this includes tokenisation and  normalisation of capital letters
- Brute force: try to parse the sentence with the original form as well as first letter uncapitalised
- Dump the grammar with `pg -words` and use that to make your own capitalisation rules (basically implementing the feature that you asked for, but separately for each grammar!)

You can also make your grammar use the `CAPIT` and `ALL_CAPIT` tokens described in [Angelov (2015)](https://aclanthology.org/W15-3305.pdf), that could solve some problems (and maybe create new ones).